# How to implement sidebar toggle in jquery with animation

Tags: jquery

Can anybody tell How to implement sidebar toggle with animation transition effect in jquery

Comment: Try googling `offcanvas`. An example: [Offcanvas - Bootstrap v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/)

Answer (score 1):

I would create this like this:

1. Create `aside` or `div` and position it absolutely on the left with CSS
2. Add `transform: translateX(-100%);` when class on body is active.

```css
body:not(.active) aside {
   transform: translateX(-100%);
}
body aside {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

and just toggle the class `active` in jQuery, CSS transition will give you an animation effect.

Alternatively, you can add class active on the sidebar and change CSS accordingly.

If the sidebar needs to be on the right then you will need to create a wrapper that has `overflow: hidden` you will need to keep in mind that you can issue with the scrollbar, but I would ask this as another question.